# File Error: Access Denied when trying to extract zip file in an S3 bucket using a lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am writing a lambda function to extract a zip file in an S3 Bucket using nodeJs but I keep receiving this error:

```
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "File Error: Access Denied",
"stack": [
    "Error: File Error: Access Denied",
    "    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index/node_modules/s3-unzip/util.js:59:24)",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:367:18)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
    "    at Request.transition (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "    at /var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/index/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)"
]
```

I am following this example: https://medium.com/@stirpude/extract-zip-file-in-s3-bucket-using-aws-lamda-functions-in-nodejs-61f19e7a6d14 but I still have the error. Also, my IAM user has an AdminstratorAccess policy. This is my code:

```
const S3Unzip = require('s3-unzip');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const bucketname = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

    new S3Unzip({
        bucket: bucketname,
        file: filename,
        verbose: true,
    }, function (err, success) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Lambdas do not run under an IAM user, but under an IAM role. Check your role’s permissions.

Comment: @Victor Thank you! As you said I didn't have the good role permission.